# What is "regomised"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

[This recent "The Register" article](https://www.theregister.com/2020/09/07/who_me/) uses a totally weird word I've never seen (emphasis mine):

> Our story comes from a reader **Regomised** as "Felix" and takes us back to the early part of this century [...]

Screenshot:

[image: The same excerpt as above, but as screenshot]

Being a non-native speaker of English I decided to ask here. I looked in two dictionaries (including one of the dead tree variety).

The use of the word in the sentence suggests it's a verb. The fact it starts with a capital letter, though, suggests otherwise. But looking at only:

> ... comes from a reader **Regomised** as "Felix" ...

... I'd still surmise that this must be a verb. The other option I pondered briefly was if it was a name/pseudonym (which conventionally start with capital letter in English), but that interpretation makes even less sense than assuming it is a verb.

When entering this in Google it assumed I was misspelling "recognized".

Is this an actual word, even slightly misspelled so that I cannot look it up or recognize it, or is this a mere spelling mistake?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking about a proprietary coining not in the lexicon.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth well, if you think. I suppose since you call it _proprietary_ I must have infringed someone's property rights by asking already . Which lexicon is the one you deem relevant? Just so I know next time not to ask here if I can't find it in the lexicon. Btw, personally I contest the very idea behind _intellectual property_ and wish to see parents, teachers and mentors receive lifelong royalties from their protégés to prove we take the concept seriously. Also the rest of the sentence was seemingly English.

Comment: Look up _proprietary_. 'Biro' is a word the proprietors are happy for you to use provided you keep the capital. 'hoover' has been genericised. But 'Regomise' is in no dictionary I've checked in. Such unrecognised inventions are off-topic on ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I know what proprietary means. Would you be so kind to provide facts then, like a trademark filing, proving your claim! [Bíró](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/László_Bíró) was the last name of an inventor of a particular  type of ballpoint pen and has also been genericised in _some_ countries to mean ball pen, while remaining a trademark. "To google" was also in no dictionary, _until it was_. And last but not least I asked because the word appeared _in an English sentence_, appeared to be a verb but somehow made little sense without further context.

Comment: I am not offended by closing the question. I got an answer and the explanation I was looking for. But I do call your rationale for the close vote into question. By the same standard every emerging neologism that hasn't made it into a dictionary cannot be asked about here. And until I see that Regomiser is a trademark (so far no indication), I don't see why you deem it proprietary. Seems like an apples and oranges thing, really.

Comment: I suggest you look up ELU policy on candidate words in ELU.Meta. ELU, as all SE sites, deals with answers that are reasonably supported by recognised authorities in the relevant domain (eg, on ELU, dictionaries).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth [Where](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is the presence of a word in the dictionary/a lexicon (tried both terms) mentioned as a prerequisite? Please don't just _vaguely_ point to "rules", point me to _the_ rule(s) which I was supposedly violating, so I can learn from my mistake. Right now it's not even clear if there was a mistake. Right now that's just your+3 opinion. On meta I only found some answers which I'd interpret as agreeing with me, but then those are never black and white. Also you still haven't provided evidence for your "proprietary" claim.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Register itself uses the term  [Regomiser](https://forums.theregister.com/post/reply/4008014) as a user name generator for its registration.  If this contributor is a "reader Regomized as 'Felix,'" it would mean a reader registered and was reassigned that random  name.

A search engine run on *Regomiser* gives more context of tech articles and suggests that it renames the user randomly.

> Today's tale from the front line of IT support comes from a reader the Regomiser has decided to call “James” and is set just as Apple's iPad moved from Jobsian[...](https://www.thetechstreetnow.com/tech/im-telling-you-i-havent-got-an-ipad-sent-from-my-ipad/16701212004960264111/16701212004960264111/)

> This week's protagonist, assigned the sobriquet of “Sarah” by the Regomiser 6000, tells a story set in modern times, although in the [...](https://www.focustechnica.com/absolutely-everyone-loves-video-conferencing-these-days-some-perhaps-a-bit-too-much/)

> Today's tale comes from a person the Regomiser has elected to call "John" and rolls back the decades to when DOS and dot-matrix ruled the[...](https://www.thetechstreetnow.com/tech/clarkes-third-law-any-sufficiently-advanced-techie-is-indistinguishable-from-magic/6536701535858087304/6536701535858087304/)

Or without one:

> The Regomiser is on recess so today's tale arises from Matt Yonkovit, main experience officer at database wrangler Percona. Yonkovit's story takes us back once[...](https://reym2000.es/sun-welcomes-vampire-dating-company-that-is-10/)

I'm going out a on bit of a "verbing weirds language" limb for etymology because aside from the Latin, I also see [*rego*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/rego) as Australian slang for vehicle registration, which makes sense for a root in the portmanteau neologism.

> 2 mass noun The action of registering, especially for an activity; registration.
>
> Origin 1960s abbreviation of registration + the colloquial suffix -o.

An [article](https://www.theregister.com/AMP/2023/11/17/on_call/) on The Register published in November 2023 confirms the meaning with a direct explanation.

> "Regomized" is a made-up portmanteau of "The Register" and "anonymized" to indicate we're not using the real names of folks who contribute stories to On-Call.

Comment: Register + anonymising = 'Regomising'.  It's a thing they do when telling stories readers have written in about disastrous workplace issues.

Comment: No source, other than reading The Register articles myself, and being a native speaker who has seen this construction all over the place.

Comment: To the helpful anonymous suggested editor of this answer to a closed question, next time please include the link.